# Need help with System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, governorlimits, data

I am receiving the following error, when trying to bulk load the customer records. Some of them are uploaded successfully, while some of them are throwing the following error.

```
<message>
AccountTrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded
</message>
<statusCode>CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY</statusCode>
```

Please find the status shown in debug logs below:

```
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 50000 out of 50000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 15026 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

There are around 800,000 existing records in the database. I think when the query in trigger is trying to match the existing records, it is throwing exception.

My question is in situations like this, we should go with Batch Apex right?

If there is any other work around, Please suggest.

Please find my trigger logic below:

```
public class AccountInsertTriggerHandler {
private List<Account> trgOldList = new List<Account> ();
private List<Account> trgNewList = new List<Account> ();
private Map<id,Account> trgOldMap = new Map<id,Account>();
private Map<id,Account> trgNewMap = new Map<id,Account>();
public Map<String,Account> leadsMap = new Map<String,Account>();
private List<String> LeadList = new List<String> ();

public AccountInsertTriggerHandler(List<Account> trgOldList,List<Account> trgNewList,Map<id,Account> trgOldMap,Map<id,Account> trgNewMap){
    this.trgOldList = trgOldList;
    this.trgNewList = trgNewList;
    this.trgOldMap = trgOldMap;
    this.trgNewMap = trgNewMap;

    for(Account acct: trgNewList){
        String UniqueCustID = acct.Region__pc + '-' + acct.PersonEmail;
        LeadList.add(UniqueCustID);
    }
    List<Account> allLeads = [select AP_21_Per_IDX__c, AP21_perIDx__pc, AP21_Code__pc, Salutation, AP21_Initials__pc, 
                                FirstName, LastName, Gender__pc, PersonBirthdate, AP21_StartDate__pc, PersonTitle, AP21_Password__pc,
                                 AP21_UpdateTimestamp__pc, AP21_Privacy__pc, AP21_Reference_Sales_rep__pc, BillingStreet, 
                                 AP21_Billing_AddressLine2__pc, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, 
                                 ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingPostalCode, 
                                 ShippingCountry, PersonEmail, Home_Phone__pc, PersonMobilePhone, Business_Phone__pc, 
                                 AP21_Loyalty_ID__pc, AP21_LoyaltyTypeID__pc, AP21_LoyaltyType__pc, AP21_Loyalty_CardNo__pc, 
                                 AP21_Loyalty_CardExpiry__pc, AP21_Loyalty_Balance__pc, AP21_Loyalty_CreditStatus__pc, 
                                 AP21_Loyalty_Message__pc, AP21_Loyalty_JoinDate__pc, AP21_LoyaltyStatusID__pc, 
                                 AP21_Loyalty_Currency__pc, AP21_Loyalty_Code__pc, AP21_Loyalty_Format__pc, Store__pc, Region__pc
                                 from Account where AP_21_Per_IDX__c = null and UniqueID__pc IN : LeadList];
    for (Account accLeads: allLeads){
        String UniqueLeadsID = accLeads.Region__pc + '-' + accLeads.PersonEmail;
        leadsMap.put(UniqueLeadsId,accLeads);
        System.debug(leadsMap);
    }
}
public void OnAfterInsert(){
    CompareCustomersToLeads(trgNewList,null);
}
/*public void OnBeforeInsert(){
    CompareCustomersToLeads(trgNewList,null);
}*/
public void CompareCustomersToLeads(List<Account> trgNewList,Map<id,Account> trgOldMap){
    //Add to map using Region and emailAddress as Key and Account record as value.Only add records from Flow User
    ////Retrieve all leads (where PerIdx is blank and created by not Flow) and create map
    ////compare similiar records in the maps i.e for each customer record in customer map, find lead record
    //compare values and update lead with PerIdx and other values
    Map<String,Account> customerMap = new Map<String,Account>();
   // Map<String,Account> leadsMap = new Map<String,Account>();
    List<Account> leadsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> customersToDelete = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc: trgNewList){
        String UniqueID = acc.Region__pc + '-' + acc.PersonEmail;
        if(leadsMap.containsKey(UniqueID)){
            customerMap.put(UniqueID,acc);
            //acc.addError('No Match to Lead hence cannot Insert');
        }

        System.debug(customerMap);

    }
    for(String key:customerMap.keySet()){
        System.debug('********KEY ' + key);
        if(leadsMap.containsKey(key)){
            Account customerRecord = customerMap.get(key);
            Account leadsRecord = leadsMap.get(key);
            System.debug(customerRecord);
            System.debug(leadsRecord);

            if(customerRecord.AP_21_Per_IDX__c!=null &&leadsRecord.AP_21_Per_IDX__c==null){
                System.debug('*********** Met Conditions');
                leadsRecord.AP_21_Per_IDX__c = customerRecord.AP_21_Per_IDX__c;
                leadsRecord.AP21_perIDx__pc = customerRecord.AP21_perIDx__pc;
                leadsRecord.FirstName = customerRecord.FirstName;
                leadsRecord.LastName = customerRecord.LastName;
                leadsRecord.PersonMobilePhone = customerRecord.PersonMobilePhone;
                if(leadsRecord.Gender__pc==null)
                    leadsRecord.Gender__pc = customerRecord.Gender__pc;
                if(leadsRecord.PersonBirthdate==null)
                    leadsRecord.PersonBirthdate = customerRecord.PersonBirthdate;
                if(leadsRecord.Store__pc==null)
                    leadsRecord.Store__pc = customerRecord.Store__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Code__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Code__pc;
                leadsRecord.Salutation = customerRecord.Salutation;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Initials__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Initials__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_StartDate__pc = customerRecord.AP21_StartDate__pc;

                leadsRecord.PersonTitle = customerRecord.PersonTitle;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Password__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Password__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_UpdateTimestamp__pc = customerRecord.AP21_UpdateTimestamp__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Privacy__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Privacy__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Reference_Sales_rep__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Reference_Sales_rep__pc;
                leadsRecord.BillingStreet = customerRecord.BillingStreet;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Billing_AddressLine2__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Billing_AddressLine2__pc;

                leadsRecord.BillingCity = customerRecord.BillingCity;
                leadsRecord.BillingState = customerRecord.BillingState;
                leadsRecord.BillingPostalCode = customerRecord.BillingPostalCode;
                leadsRecord.BillingCountry = customerRecord.BillingCountry;

                leadsRecord.ShippingStreet = customerRecord.ShippingStreet;
                leadsRecord.ShippingCity = customerRecord.ShippingCity;
                leadsRecord.ShippingState = customerRecord.ShippingState;
                leadsRecord.ShippingPostalCode = customerRecord.ShippingPostalCode;
                leadsRecord.ShippingCountry = customerRecord.ShippingCountry;
                leadsRecord.PersonEmail = customerRecord.PersonEmail;
                if(leadsRecord.Home_Phone__pc==null)
                 leadsRecord.Home_Phone__pc = customerRecord.Home_Phone__pc;
                if(leadsRecord.PersonMobilePhone==null)
                 leadsRecord.PersonMobilePhone = customerRecord.PersonMobilePhone;
                if(leadsRecord.Business_Phone__pc==null)
                 leadsRecord.Business_Phone__pc = customerRecord.Business_Phone__pc;



                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_ID__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_ID__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_LoyaltyTypeID__pc = customerRecord.AP21_LoyaltyTypeID__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_LoyaltyType__pc = customerRecord.AP21_LoyaltyType__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_CardNo__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_CardNo__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_CardExpiry__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_CardExpiry__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Balance__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Balance__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_CreditStatus__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_CreditStatus__pc;

                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Message__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Message__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_JoinDate__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_JoinDate__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_LoyaltyStatusID__pc = customerRecord.AP21_LoyaltyStatusID__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Currency__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Currency__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Code__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Code__pc;
                leadsRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Format__pc = customerRecord.AP21_Loyalty_Format__pc;
                leadsRecord.Region__pc = customerRecord.Region__pc;




                leadsToUpdate.add(leadsRecord);

                customersToDelete.add(customerRecord);
            }

        }
    }
    update leadsToUpdate;
    List<Account> deleteCustomers = [select id from Account where id IN: customersToDelete];
    delete deleteCustomers;

}
```

}

Please find the debug log after removing the debug statements in production code:

```
10:09:58.714 (18562455772)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[152]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id FROM Account WHERE id IN :tmpVar1 LIMIT 50000
```

10:09:58.714 (18569696442)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[152]|Rows:1
10:09:58.714 (18569734502)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[152]|System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
10:09:58.714 (18569853312)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[152]|Bytes:30
10:09:58.714 (18569880194)|METHOD_EXIT|[47]|01p7F00000O4xqM|AccountInsertTriggerHandler.CompareCustomersToLeads(List, Map)
10:09:58.714 (18569890597)|METHOD_EXIT|[4]|01p7F00000O4xqM|AccountInsertTriggerHandler.OnAfterInsert()
10:09:58.714 (18569947597)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Class.AccountInsertTriggerHandler.CompareCustomersToLeads: line 152, column 1
Class.AccountInsertTriggerHandler.OnAfterInsert: line 47, column 1
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 4, column 1
10:09:58.714 (18569960836)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Class.AccountInsertTriggerHandler.CompareCustomersToLeads: line 152, column 1
Class.AccountInsertTriggerHandler.OnAfterInsert: line 47, column 1
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 4, column 1
10:09:59.570 (18570083066)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
10:09:59.570 (18570083066)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 2 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 50001 out of 50000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 3 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 5296 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

10:09:59.570 (18570083066)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

10:09:58.714 (18571196926)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|AccountTrigger on Account trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/AccountTrigger
10:09:58.714 (18572303315)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Answer (score 2):

Your debug statements are sucking the performance right out of your code. **Never** leave debug statements in production code. And I do mean **never**. Let me give you a trivial example.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> values = new Map<Integer, Integer>();
for(Integer i = 0; i < 7500; i++) {
    values.put(i, i);
    system.debug('item'+values);
}
```

This code tries to put 7,500 items into a map. It requires about 9.7 seconds to run:

```
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 9714 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

Now, we remove the debug statement:

```
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

The script took so little time it didn't even *register* in the governor limits. The exact same code minus debug statements. Now, I'm not saying that this *will* fix your issue, but considering that you're using debug statements in every single loop, I can pretty much guarantee it'll save at least 5 seconds of CPU time, if not more.

If you find yourself in a position where you need to debug, use [checkpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5) instead. They will give you a complete memory graph at any arbitrary point of execution, and when you're done, you can disable them so they don't take up tons of CPU time.

Comment: How to handle when you have to debug in prod?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Use checkpoints.

Comment: This is not apex active debugger right? It hardly works if you have too many batches nd queable queued

Comment: @sfdcfox I will remove the debug statements, and will check the performance. Thanks for teaching about that. Just one question. If we want to write a logic, where we have to check the existing records in database (Say some 800,00), which is the best way to go? The thing that comes to my mind is to Write a batch apex and schedule it to run at some time. Please let me know if you have anything to add to this

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Correct. Debug statements in general are performance killers and must be avoided in production code at all costs. We're not talking about the debugger; if you need to use it, you're already in a sandbox and can see all data in memory and the current line of execution.

Comment: @Raj Optimizing your trigger code to use the unique ID values you're using should be sufficient. I don't think your particular use case is a need for batch apex. For example, we successfully duplicate over 4,000,000 records in real time in a trigger. It requires some effort, but it's not impossible.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have removed the debug statements in production code, and yes the CPU timeout error was gone, but close to the limit. Please see the attached debug log in the main question. I am getting the "System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001". I have specified as LIMIT 50000 in the queries. Doesn't that work?

Comment: @Raj the 50,000 row limit is cumulative across all queries within a transaction. Putting LIMIT 50000 means you have no query rows left for whatever remaining queries you may have. You are doing to need to do more optimization; this answer was very specifically aimed at the original problem, which was the CPU timeout because of too many debug statements.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for that answer. learning a lot from your answers. Can I limit the query to 10000 records? Will that work?

Comment: @Raj I'd try to figure out why you're querying 50k rows in a query. It seems to me that something is amiss with your data.

Comment: @sfdcfox Now the code is working fine after limiting the no of records returned by the query. Commenting the debug statements worked very well. Thanks for your support